# show liked users list in php

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have an array containing name. I am trying to display two names and remaining user names as count of others. I tried this, but i got some problem. This is the code i tried

```
$names = array('Daan', 'John', 'Jack', 'George');
$numberOfNames = count($names);

if($numberOfNames <= 2) {
    foreach($names as $name) {
        echo $name;
    }
} else {
    $count = 0;
    foreach($names as $name) {
        if($count == 2) {
            echo "and " .$numberOfNames - 2. "others";
        } else {
            echo $name;
        }

        $count++;
    }
}
```

result

```
Daan, Jones, and 3 othersFrederick, Lisa,
```

after 3 other (no of count) again it shows name.

Comment: You're looping through the whole list, just checking to see if you're on a specific iteration. You need to terminate the loop at that point, if you don't want to carry on outputting the rest of the names.

Answer (score 0):

What is the point of the two loops? You don't need ANY loops for this:

```
echo $names[0], " and ", $names[1], " and ", count($names) - 2, " others";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$names = array('Daan', 'John', 'Jack', 'George');
$numberOfNames = count($names);

echo $names[0].", ".$names[1]." $numberOfNames other like this";`
```

Answer (score 0):

Marc B is right.

If for some reason you like to type a lot of useless code, you should add a *break;* at *$count == 2*.

```
<?php 
$names = array('Daan', 'John', 'Jack', 'George');
$numberOfNames = count($names);


if ($numberOfNames <= 2) {
    foreach ($names as $name) {
        echo $name;
    }
} else {
$count = 0;
foreach ($names as $name) {
    if ($count == 2) {
        echo "and " . ($numberOfNames - 2) . " others";
        break;
        } else {
        echo $name . ", ";
        }
    $count++;
    }
}
```

Or you could also do it like this:

```
<?php 
$names = array('Daan', 'John', 'Jack', 'George');
$numberOfNames = count($names);

for ($i = 0; $i <= 2; $i++) {
    if ( $i < 2 ) {
        echo $names[$i] . ", ";
    } else {
        echo "and " . ($numberOfNames - 2) . " others";
    }
}
```